# New questions getting buried in old questions

Tags: discussion, moderators

I am not asking this question to criticize or nullify someone's effort. I have been noticing that since the last few days, when @Pheo started editing (which is a good thing) that new questions which are being asked by "new" users are getting minimum views.

My question is should the "moderators" accept so many edits at a single time so that new questions get buried among the old questions? The old questions have a clear advantage in terms of reputation of the OP, views, upvotes, and general title. So what does the moderators think is a solution to the problem?

Comment: I think a solution would be to pin a question, and have a list of new questions on it. Re-create the "active questions" slide. Just a friendly input from me. :)

Comment: Maybe we could take a look at some of SmokeDetectors code? Salvage something from there, and make a new question feed. Or, as I have recently seen, we could scrap some from the AI meta Questions Feed bot.

Comment: Hey, is there any way we can watch this: https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime, with something automated?

Comment: @Pheo Your suggestions here only address a small portion of the issue. For the significant majority of users, they are just going to use the tabs/pages which are available as stock destinations from SE. If anyone wants to see just new questions, they can do that, at least on a tag-by-tag basis. Nothing that's done to create a new, non-stock place for people to go will result in most people who already use the home page moving away from doing so. Thus, that type of solution won't solve the problem.

Comment: On SO, this type of bulk cleanup, particularly by users without full edit privileges, is not encouraged, for precisely this reason (i.e. it disrupts the use of the site for a significant number of people and harms the reception of new questions). When done, it's requested that the user either: edits all posts they are going to do in one large set, so the disruption to the homepage/tag activity pages is confined to one time and rolls off; or only does a few, every few days (or every day, if question volume is high enough), so those pages remain *primarily* questions not involved in these edits.

Comment: @Pheo In addition, it's requested that the user correct *all* problems, at least those that are obvious, which you have not done in some cases. In addition, some of your edits have been what I'd consider [pedantic formatting choices](//ai.stackexchange.com/posts/79/revisions). I'm not saying they're necessarily wrong, but I wouldn't edit/bump a post just to make that sort of change, as it doesn't actually help readability. I *certainly* wouldn't edit for just removing double spaces between a period and the first word in a sentence (a style choice by the OP, which while antiquated, is valid).

Comment: @Makyen what you are doing has a side effect of discouraging me. I understand that any method that moves users away from the main page is not a good habit. I also happen to understand the difference between users with edit privs, and those without. I also happen to want you to note that the number of posts to be edited is *__massive__*. I (I hope others are also) am working back from page 103 on the questions list. As for the edit privs, I hope to reach those soon. As for being pedantic, that is one of my greatest skills: feedback. And things that are valid are not necessarily valid still.

Comment: Apart from that I agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found a solution to this.

Until I attain edit privileges, I am only going to do a few posts a week - Making sure that everything on them is as it should be (Taking critical issues into consideration first). As much as this is going to slow the progress down, the quality will go up greatly. As a plus, I will have more practice and a lot more time for feedback per capita per post.

I hope the majority of you stand with me, but regardless, I am going to do this. Please note, I have not drawn into the shell of seclusion, but merely been scolded and found a corner for myself to sit in for a while.

#### TL;DR

I am going to be cutting back on the number of time per post and increasing the time spent on each post. In other words, keeping the impact down.

Comment: As a wider community, all the SE sites encourage editing to improve quality and it has always been a challenge balancing the improvements with the front page bumping. Taking things a little bit slower, especially on a lower traffic site, is going to help. Remember, once you have edit privs, edits will still bump a post to the front page. They will just require less effort.

Comment: Thanks for moderating your initiative.  "Moderation in all things!" *(but, that can also apply to moderation itself;)*

Comment: @DukeZhou Sometimes you have to change when the ways get hard.

Answer (score 2):

For years, users have asked Stack Exchange to add an option not to bump a question/answer when it gets edited. Until this gets implemented, there will be some awkward balance between keeping imperfect content that could be edited and not burying new questions.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in.  I recognize DuttaA's concern, and there was an initial flood, but imo, it can also be useful to bring some of the old questions to light for subsequent evaluation.

Comment: @DukeZhou yes: bumping should be optional